# I need mysql query to generate following result

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `form_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=shortfor;2=longfom',
    `remote_addr` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
    `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=impression;2=click;3=conversion',
    `website_url` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `c_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `form_id` (`form_id` , `remote_addr` , `type` , `website_url`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64;
```

i want to total count impression,click,conversion.
i want group by website url  group by impression,group by click ,group by conversion.
how to wright query? please help me i need to emergency !!!!! 
![enter image description here][1]

I need  following result

```
website url----------Impression----click--converison-----
192.1.1.1--------------1-----------2------1--------------
192.1.1.2--------------3-----------2------2--------------
192.1.1.3--------------4-----------3------1--------------
192.1.1.4--------------2-----------6------1--------------
```

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: Actually I have table structure above and In that  I have multiple website url so I want to group by website url and so count their impression,click and conversion from `type` field. In this  I have to to two group by so I am confused.

Comment: @RonakChauhan Thanks its working fine and generating result what i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try below query

```
$sql = "SELECT website_url,SUM(type=1) as impression,SUM(type=2) as click,SUM(type=3) as conversion  FROM `test` GROUP BY website_url";
```

Let me know this is the way you need.